# id parameter on link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, link-to

My question it's very simple, but I don't find a solution.

I'm using:

- Rails 3.0.9
- ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18 revision 30909) [x86_64-linux]

The question it's:

In older rails version when create a link using link_to function, like this:

```
link_to owner.name,
    {
        :controller => 'owner',
        :action => 'view',
        :id => owner
    },
    :title => owner.name
```

Returns:

```
<a href="/owner/view/10001" title="Bla, bla, bla, bla">I'm using rails</a>
```

But now (in rails 3) it's returning:

```
<a href="/owner/view?id=10001" title="Bla, bla, bla, bla">I'm using rails</a>
```

Thanks in advance.

P.S: I'm a newbie english spoken.

Comment: Do you have routes configured for this owner controller?

Comment: No... ??? routes for controller ??? No firmly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify you root in routes.rb:

```
match '/owner/view/:id' => 'owner#view', :as => :owner_view
```

and then use it like this:

```
link_to owner.name, owner_view_path(owner)
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
link_to owner.name, owner, :title => owner.name
```

If your action is `detail`, then:

```
link_to owner.name, [:detail, owner], :title => owner.name
```

And be sure that your `detail` action is included in your routes

Comment: if then action url parameter it's different? on example: `:action => 'detail'`